# Problem with the process list (process.title)

Tags: node.js, process

I have a question to ask you, I have looked at the list of `processes` and there is one that intrigues me, it can `return` the `title` of the `process`. I was wondering if you can change the title and if so how?

Source:  [List of all process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processtitle)

I wanted to use `process.title` like this: `process.title("Heyy !")`.

but it didn't work. So I was wondering if you can really change the title and if so how?

Comment: `process.title = "Heyy !"`

Comment: thank you very much! (sorry if it was stupid)